# Redirect mapping for media items in Sitecore

Tags: sxa, redirect, seo

Is there any way we can `redirect mapping`  of media item in `Sitecore SXA` just like `redirect map` of the page?

Answer (score -1):

Either you can customize SXA redirect pipeline to support Media redirect or you can use IIS level redirects.

Hope this information will help full for you.

Thanks.